# Polymer Multiple Iron-Collapse

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

The polymer docs aren't clear on how to create a multiple toggle using iron-collapse. Is there an easy way to get each item to toggle? I had a look at [multiple iron-collapse not working, expands only first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35653441/multiple-iron-collapse-not-working-expands-only-first) but I could not get it to work. Maybe something has changed in polymer since then. Below is an example of the code I am using.

```
<div on-click="toggle"><paper-item><a class="paper-item-link"><strong>List Items</strong></a></paper-item></div>
<iron-collapse id="collapse">
<div>Content</div>
</iron-collapse>

<div on-click="toggle"><paper-item><a class="paper-item-link"><strong>List Items</strong></a></paper-item></div>
<iron-collapse id="collapse">
<div>Content</div>
</iron-collapse>

  toggle: function() {
    this.$.collapse.toggle();
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer's [automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding) maps nodes by their IDs, but you have two nodes with the same ID, so only the last one encountered would be mapped to that ID (i.e., `this.$.collapse` refers to the second `iron-collapse` in your example). Also, since your `click`-handler refers to the same `iron-collapse`, both `paper-item`s would toggle the same `iron-collapse` when clicked.

The quickest solution would be to use unique node IDs for each `iron-collapse` and to use unique `click` handlers:

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v1.9.2/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-collapse/iron-collapse.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <div on-click="toggle1">
        <paper-item>
          <a class="paper-item-link"><strong>List Items</strong></a>
        </paper-item>
      </div>
      <iron-collapse id="collapse1">
        <div>Content</div>
      </iron-collapse>

      <div on-click="toggle2">
        <paper-item>
          <a class="paper-item-link"><strong>List Items</strong></a>
        </paper-item>
      </div>
      <iron-collapse id="collapse2">
        <div>Content</div>
      </iron-collapse>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          toggle1: function() {
            this.$.collapse1.toggle();
          },
          toggle2: function() {
            this.$.collapse2.toggle();
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QEGROO?editors=1000)